# Importações no arquivo __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Estou estudando a documentação do `Django` e notei que em alguns arquivos `__init__.py` existem importações, sei que o arquivo `__init__.py` define um módulo mas não entendi o porquê das importações no mesmo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O arquivo `__init__.py` é o *entry point* do pacote.

Quando você faz, por exemplo:

```
from django import *
```

O que você está importando será o contexto definido em `django/__init__.py` - limitado, obviamente, pelo objeto `__all__` se este estiver definido no arquivo. Isso se dá justamente para você trabalhar com o escopo que é disponibilizado aos usuários do pacote.

Perceba, por exemplo, que se você fizer:

```
from django import get_version
```

Você conseguirá importar a função `get_version` com sucesso, mesmo que a função nem esteja declarada em `django/__init__.py`. O que acontece é que no arquivo `__init__.py` do Django há a instrução:

```
from django.utils.version import get_version
```

Que importa a função de onde ela é declarada para o escopo em `__init__.py` e, assim, ficando também disponível diretamente no escopo do pacote.

A biblioteca Flask também faz isso, para disponibilizar as classes básicas de uma forma mais direta:

```
__version__ = '1.1.dev'

# utilities we import from Werkzeug and Jinja2 that are unused
# in the module but are exported as public interface.
from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
from werkzeug.utils import redirect
from jinja2 import Markup, escape

from .app import Flask, Request, Response
from .config import Config
```

<sup>Trecho de código retirado do [repositório oficial do Flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/__init__.py)</sup>

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigado pela excelente resposta.

Answer (score 1):

(Um outro exemplo, apesar de já terem respondido)

Elas ajudam na organização do código. Geralmente importamos funções e classes mais utilizadas no `__init__.py`.

Dada essa arquitetura:

```
diretorio_1/
    __init__.py
    arquivo.py
    arquivo2.py
    arquivo3.py
    ...
    arquivo20.py
    subdiretorio/
        __init__.py
        possui_funcao_soma.py
        possui_funcao_subtracao.py
```

Imagine que temos em um diretório com 20 aquivos .py que usam uma função soma() e subtracao() de um arquivo chamado possui_funcao_soma.py e possui_funcao_subtracao.py do subdiretorio. Em vez de escrever em todos os 20 arquivos

```
from subdiretorio.possui_funcao_soma import soma
from subdiretorio.possui_funcao_subtracao import subtracao
```

Escrevemos:

```
#No __init__.py do subdiretorio
from possui_funcao_soma import soma
from possui_funcao_subtracao import subtracao

#Nos 20 arquivos do diretorio
from subdiretorio import soma, subtracao
```

Uma vantagem de fazer isso é que não precisa ficar verificando onde está a função que quer importar, ela pode ser acessada mais fácil se já foi importada no `__init__.py`.